# Rails join with where using AND instead of OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a scope (where `title` is an array)

```
scope :with_label, ->(title) { joins(:labels).where(labels: { title: title }) }
```

By default this does an `AND` query. How can I get this to do an `OR` query? I can't seem to find any examples of this.

I believe this is the SQL that is generated:

```
Label Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "labels".* FROM "labels" WHERE "labels"."project_id" = $1 AND "labels"."title" = $2  ORDER BY "labels"."title" ASC LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 8], ["title", "label1,label2,label3"]]
```

Comment: what database are you using? with Postgres using an array like this doesn't result in an `AND` or an `OR` query, but `IN`, with the values from the array put into parentheses

Comment: can you post the SQL output of one of your queries? as mentioned above, postgres should have `IN` for this use of an array

Comment: @sixty4bit I've posted what I found

Comment: thanks, I've posed an answer but I don't think it's covering everything that's going on here. can you post what model the scope belongs to and the code you are running that generates the SQL up there?

Comment: @sixty4bit It's part of a much larger project. I don't know how the sql get's output. The scope belongs to model called `Problem`.

Comment: It's hard to answer the question without seeing the ruby code and the sql it generates. I have no idea if the SQL you posted above actually has anything to do with the scope. It's not clear e.g. where `project_id` is coming from. What is a project and what is it's relationship to a `Problem`, a `Label`, and the scope above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108581/discussion-between-johnston-and-sixty4bit).

Answer (score 2):

Rails/ActiveRecord only supports `OR` queries [in Rails 5](http://juanitofatas.com/2015/01/31/rails-5-active-record-or/). In earlier versions, you need to use a SQL string to achieve an `OR` query:

`Widget.where("name = ? OR name = ?", "foo", "bar") # postgres`

When there are many possibilities, the same thing can be accomplished more efficiently with an `IN` query, which is generated in ActiveRecord by passing an array with more than one element to the `#where` method:

```
arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
Widget.where(name: arr)
```

As for the SQL output you've posted:

```
Label Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "labels".* FROM "labels" WHERE "labels"."project_id" = $1 AND "labels"."title" = $2  ORDER BY "labels"."title" ASC LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 8], ["title", "label1,label2,label3"]]
```

The `AND` here is coming from the fact that a query is being made against the `product_id` as well as the `title`, not because of anything to do with `title`.